# Very high cost for low limit LIMIT / high OFFSET

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, explain

I'm having very large table with products. I need to select several products at very high offset (example below). Postgresql manual on indexes and performance suggests to create index on column that's used by ORDER BY + eventual conditions. Everything is peachy, no sort is used. but for high offset values LIMIT is very costly. Anyone have any idea what might be a cause for that?

Following query can run for minutes.

```
Indexes:
"product_slugs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_for_listing_by_default_active" btree (priority DESC, name, active)
"index_for_listing_by_name_active" btree (name, active)
"index_for_listing_by_price_active" btree (master_price, active)
"product_slugs_product_id" btree (product_id)

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM "product_slugs" WHERE ("product_slugs"."active" = 1) ORDER BY product_slugs.name ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 14859;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=26571.55..26589.43 rows=10 width=1433)
   ->  Index Scan using index_for_listing_by_name_active on product_slugs  (cost=0.00..290770.61 rows=162601 width=1433)
         Index Cond: (active = 1)
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `index_for_listing_by_name_active` index you have here isn't going to help much, since the products in the result set aren't necessarily going to be contiguous in the index. Try creating a conditional index by name on only those products which are active:

```
CREATE INDEX index_for_listing_active_by_name
  ON product_slugs (name)
  WHERE product_slugs.active = 1;
```

Comment: So far looks good, I'll leave both for tonight and we'll see tommorow. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: nice to see someone remembering conditional indices exist instead of simply saying to switch the order of the index columns :)

Comment: I tried swapping the column order in a test database and it didn't seem to help — in fact, it did significantly worse. I'm not sure what the story was, but I would have expected it to help.

Comment: I've experimented a lot with indexes, In fact I've tried conditional indexes early on, and they didn't seem to help, but after that I've changed query structure, and now they just hit the jackpot.
Anyway changing order didn't help earlier, also active is not very selective 80% of products are active.